# WindowInsetListener doubles offset in Android R (Api 30)

Tags: java, android, android-softkeyboard, windowinsets

I wrote a keyboard animation to make a control (any view) follow the slide-in and slide-out animation of the Softkeyboard.
In Android 10 and below everything works fine.

I took the idea from this (meanwhile) outdated article at [proandroiddev](https://proandroiddev.com/animating-keyboard-appearance-in-android-application-425a2a26de9a) (written before Android 11 and unfortunately written in Kotlin and it also doesn't care much about deprecated methods), but translation to Java worked fine - the only Problem left is with Api30+

In Android 11, when the animation ends, the `WindowInsetListener` (or the `delayedTransition`, I don't know what causes the issue) seems to double the offset (i.e. adds the full height of the Softkeyboard a second time to the views' bounds).

See those two gif's showing the differences (Sorry for the quality - I am not too deep into video recording).

Same code running on both devices.

**Android 10 on the left, Android 11 on the right**

[image: Android 10] [image: Android 11]

Here is the Listener:

```java
class WindowInsetsListener implements View.OnApplyWindowInsetsListener {
    private final KeyboardAnimationListener animationListener;
    private int previousOffset = 0;
    
    WindowInsetsListener(KeyboardAnimationListener animationListener) {
        this.animationListener = animationListener;
    }
    
    @Override
    public WindowInsets onApplyWindowInsets(View decorView, WindowInsets insets) {
        WindowInsets result = insets;
        int offset = insets.getSystemWindowInsetBottom() < insets.getStableInsetBottom() ?
                insets.getSystemWindowInsetBottom() :
                insets.getSystemWindowInsetBottom() - insets.getStableInsetBottom();
        
        if (offset != previousOffset && animationListener.animate(decorView, offset)) {
            previousOffset = offset;
            result = consumeBottomInset(insets);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
                return WindowInsets.CONSUMED;
            }
        }
        
        return decorView.onApplyWindowInsets(result);
    }
    
    private WindowInsets consumeBottomInset(WindowInsets insets) {
        Rect insetRect = new Rect(
            insets.getSystemWindowInsetLeft(),
            insets.getSystemWindowInsetTop(),
            insets.getSystemWindowInsetRight(),
            Math.min(insets.getSystemWindowInsetBottom(), insets.getStableInsetBottom()));
        
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            Insets newInsets = Insets.of(insetRect);
            
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
                return new WindowInsets.Builder().
                    setInsets(WindowInsets.Type.systemBars(), newInsets).build();
            } else {
                return new WindowInsets.Builder().
                    setSystemWindowInsets(newInsets).build();
            }
        } else {
            return insets.replaceSystemWindowInsets(insetRect);
        }
    }
```

Here is my animate Method called from the Listener:

```java
    @Override
    public boolean animate(@NonNull View view, int offset) {
        ViewGroup group = getGroup(view); // searches the hierarchy up until it finds the group
        if (group != null) {
            TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(group, bounds);
            setBottomPadding(view, offset);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected void setBottomPadding(View view, int offset) {
        view.setPadding(
            view.getPaddingLeft(),
            view.getPaddingTop(),
            view.getPaddingRight(),
            offset);
    }
```

I tried to respect all deprecations through the versions. Especially this part of Android changed in every version. But even if I take out the "new" implementations for Api 29 and 30 and when I use the deprecated `.replaceSystemWindowInsets` method, the effect stays the same.

Anyone has an idea about additional flags or something else that needs to be supplied in Api 30+?

Comment: since android 11 it is possible to sync the ime keyboard with the content via view.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener, take a look to https://proandroiddev.com/exploring-windowinsets-on-android-11-a80cf8fe19be